# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<double>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

I'm trying to map a document with different user data from a Firebase Firestore database. The error occurs when I try to cast values different from dynamic (lists in this case). Down there there is the part of code where I map the Firebase document and the user model.
The method where the error occurs:

```
void appUser() async {
    final String id = await PathUtils().readID();
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id.toString());
    documentReference.get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        final data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        print(data);
        //final userValues = data.values.toList();
        final AppUser user = AppUser(
          email: data['email'],
          userName: data['userName'],
          listaSchede: data['listaSchede'],
          latestWorkouts: data['latestWorkouts'],
          volumeTot: data['volumeTot'],
          volumeSettimanale: data['volumeSettimanale'],
          listaPesi: data['listaPesi'],
          pesoAttuale: data['pesoAttuale'],
          altezza: data['altezza'],
          age: data['età'],
          circBicipiti: data['circBicipiti'],
          listaCircBicipiti: data['listaCircBicipiti'],
          circTricipiti: data['circTricipiti'],
          listaCircTricipiti: data['listaCircTricipit'],
          circVita: data['circVita'],
          listaCircVita: data['listaCircVita'],
          id: data['id'],
          createdAt: data['createdAt'],
        );
        print(user.toMap());
        state = user;
      },
      onError: (e) {
        print('error: $e');
      },
    );
  }
```

user model:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:gym/models/scheda_model.dart';
import 'package:gym/models/workout_model.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

const Uuid uuid = Uuid();

class AppUser {
  AppUser(
      {required this.email,
      required this.userName,
      required this.listaSchede,
      required this.latestWorkouts,
      required this.volumeTot,
      required this.volumeSettimanale,
      required this.listaPesi,
      required this.pesoAttuale,
      required this.altezza,
      required this.age,
      required this.circBicipiti,
      required this.listaCircBicipiti,
      required this.circTricipiti,
      required this.listaCircTricipiti,
      required this.circVita,
      required this.listaCircVita,
      required this.id,
      required this.createdAt});

  factory AppUser.createNewUser({
    required String? email,
    required String password,
    required String userName,
    String? id,
  }) {
    return AppUser(
      id: id ?? uuid.v4(),
      email: email,
      userName: userName,
      listaSchede: [],
      latestWorkouts: [],
      volumeTot: 0.0,
      volumeSettimanale: [],
      listaPesi: [],
      pesoAttuale: 0.0,
      altezza: 0.0,
      age: 0,
      circBicipiti: 0,
      listaCircBicipiti: [],
      circTricipiti: 0,
      listaCircTricipiti: [],
      circVita: 0,
      listaCircVita: [],
      createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    );
  }

  final String? email;
  final String userName;
  final String id;
  final List<Scheda> listaSchede; //Scehda is another custom model
  final double volumeTot;
  final List<double> volumeSettimanale;
  final List<Workout> latestWorkouts; //Workout is another custom model
  final List<double> listaPesi;
  final double pesoAttuale;
  final double altezza;
  final int age;
  final double circBicipiti;
  final List<double> listaCircBicipiti;
  final double circTricipiti;
  final List<double> listaCircTricipiti;
  final double circVita;
  final List<double> listaCircVita;
  final FieldValue createdAt;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'email': email,
      'userName': userName,
      'listaSchede': listaSchede,
      'latestWorkouts': latestWorkouts,
      'volumeTot': volumeTot,
      'volumeSettimanale': volumeSettimanale,
      'listaPesi': listaPesi,
      'pesoAttuale': pesoAttuale,
      'altezza': altezza,
      'age': age,
      'circBicipiti': circBicipiti,
      'listaCircBicipiti': listaCircBicipiti,
      'circTricipiti': circTricipiti,
      'listaCircTricpiti': listaCircTricipiti,
      'circVita': circVita,
      'listaCircVita': listaCircVita,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
    };
  }
}
```

the full error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<double>'
#0      UserState.appUser.<anonymous closure>
user_provider.dart:52
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      UserState.appUser.<anonymous closure>
user_provider.dart:42
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is a sample of print(data):

```
 {id: hzQAvGSdFOab8VwewJSWhCGiTpu1, listaPesi: [], pesoAttuale: 4.0, age: 232, circBicipiti: 0.0, latestWorkouts: [], circTricipiti: 0.0, altezza: 43.0, listaSchede: [], userName: asdgdsf, volumeSettimanale: [], circVita: 0.0, listaCircVita: [], volumeTot: 0.0, listaCircTricpiti: [], email: sdgsdg@mfds.com, createdAt: Timestamp(seconds=1692893432, nanoseconds=646000000), listaCircBicipiti: []}
```

Comment: Share the example of data (print(data)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issues in this way:

- I add a .fromDataMap() method for Scheda and Workout (which is shown down there)
- I edited the 'simplest' lists in a few lines of code form which you can extract a method (I'll do that another time)

The method I added in Scheda and Workout models:

```
factory Scheda.fromDataMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
return Scheda(
  id: data['id'],
  workoutList: List<Workout>.from(
      data['workoutList'].map((w) => Workout.fromDataMap(w))),
  title: data['title'],
  isActive: data['isActive'],
);
  }
```

(for workout model)

```
factory Workout.fromDataMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<dynamic> rawWorkoutList = data['workoutList'];
    final List<PersonalExercise> workoutList = rawWorkoutList
        .map((workoutData) => workoutData as PersonalExercise)
        .toList();

    if (data['duration'] == null) {
      return Workout(
        exerciseList: workoutList,
        title: data['title'],
      );
    }
    return Workout(
      exerciseList: workoutList,
      title: data['title'],
      duration: data['duration'],
    );
  }
```

Finally, how I used that code:

```
final List<dynamic> rawSchedeList = data['listaSchede'];
        final List<Scheda> schedeList = rawSchedeList
            .map((schedaData) => Scheda.fromDataMap(schedaData))
            .toList();

        final List<dynamic> rawLatestWorkouts = data['latestWorkouts'];
        final List<Workout> latestWorkouts = rawLatestWorkouts
            .map((workData) => Workout.fromDataMap(workData))
            .toList();

        final List<dynamic> rawVolumeSet = data['volumeSettimanale'];
        final List<double> volumeSet = rawVolumeSet
            .map((volumeSingolo) => double.parse(volumeSingolo))
            .toList(); //... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You have define data as `List<double>` but you receive `List<dynamic>` you must check

```
volumeSettimanale
listaPesi
listaCircBicipiti
listaCircTricipiti
listaCircVita
```

make sure your firestore data type matches your model data type.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that if I can or not add a List of custom models on Firestore. Can I?

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse data hard coding use `fromMap` and always remember never typecast `LIST`

```
    return AppUser(
      email: map['email'] != null ? map['email'] as String : null,
      userName: map['userName'] as String,
      id: map['id'] as String,
      listaSchede: List<Scheda>.from(
        (map['listaSchede'] as List<int>).map<Scheda>(
          (x) => Scheda.fromMap(x as Map<String, dynamic>),
        ),
      ),
      volumeTot: map['volumeTot'] as double,
      volumeSettimanale: List<double>.from((map['volumeSettimanale'])),
      latestWorkouts: List<Workout>.from(
        (map['latestWorkouts'] as List<int>).map<Workout>(
          (x) => Workout.fromMap(x as Map<String, dynamic>),
        ),
      ),
      listaPesi: List<double>.from((map['listaPesi'])),
      pesoAttuale: map['pesoAttuale'] as double,
      altezza: map['altezza'] as double,
      age: map['age'] as int,
      circBicipiti: map['circBicipiti'] as double,
      listaCircBicipiti: List<double>.from((map['listaCircBicipiti'])),
      circTricipiti: map['circTricipiti'] as double,
      listaCircTricipiti: List<double>.from((map['listaCircTricipiti'])),
      circVita: map['circVita'] as double,
      listaCircVita: List<double>.from((map['listaCircVita'])),
    );
  }
`
```

Comment: You may be right, however, the same initial error occurs because you are trying to do the same cast I did previously in listaSchede: ....

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to cast to `double`, something like this:

```
data['volumeSettimanale'].cast<double>()
```

Comment: You can cast a single value (and I don't need to do that), but if you cast a List, it shows this error: _TypeError (type 'CastList<dynamic, List<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<double>')